# Need a field description inside an input field without sending it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a contact form and I want the descriptions of the fields inside the input field. If I add the description by "value" I got the problem that this value will be send and an other problem is that this value will not be hide if I click inside the input field.

Is there any easy solution?

Thats the simple input field I talking about: [jsfiddle.net/gefxo2s3/](http://jsfiddle.net/gefxo2s3/)

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="textinput" value="Your E-Mail">
```

Comment: Try using the `placeholder` attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 placeholder attribute

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
```

is what you are looking for. Works in most browsers [[browser support stats](http://caniuse.com/#search=input-placeholder)], but there are polyfills for those browsers that don't support it. I suggest [this one](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize! Enjoy your placeholders in the mean time ;)